# How do I specify (no scope) for GitHub login

Tags: firebase, github-api, firebasesimplelogin

According to [the GitHub auth documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes), as the developer I can request "(no scope)" - which I assume they expect to be a null or missing attribute in the request - but Firebase seems to default me to "user" scope if I don't supply a scope in the firebase simple login request. I'm following the [Firebase docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/simple-login/github.html), and in fact I can manipulate scope (I added more, but I cannot take away).

I want no scope because I simply want to be able to prevent the request limit from being hit too quickly on the github API.

Comment: I'd try giving it an empty string, since the docs say it is a comma-separated string which defaults to `"user"`. And failing that, have you tried a literal `"(no scope)"`?

Comment: Hey @Leeft thanks for the suggestion. Sadly, I tried both, and in both cases they default to "user". I'm hoping that someone from Firebase will see this post (it says they watch the tag closely on their support page).

Comment: Oh we're watching you. So you'd better be on your best behavior! Looks like this feature is already in testing and should go live circa next month.

Comment: @Kato Brillopads! I'm working on a really cool GitHub integration but my privacy-cynical friend had a go at me for asking for write access to his profile. I'm looking forward to the update, keep up the good work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this with Firebase Simple Login at this time.

Firebase acknowledges that this has been requested, and indicates that it's currently under development. I'll update this answer with some sample code once it has been released.

(This answer is mostly copied out of the comments on the question)